# PDO Singleton Class, am i doing it right?

Tags: php, pdo, singleton

I'm working on a new project. On this project I've used a pdo singleton class which I am using for the first time and I don't know if I'm doing it right.

Would be nice if you could give me tips or improvements.

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

class Database
{
  private $_config;
  private $_instance = null;

  public function __construct($config)
  {
    $this->_config = $config;
  }

  public function getInstance()
  {
    if ($this->_instance == null) {
      try {
        $this->_instance = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->_config['database']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $this->_config['database']['name'] . ';charset=' . $this->_config['database']['charset'], $this->_config['database']['username'], $this->_config['database']['password'], [
          \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
        ]);
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
      }
    }

    return $this->_instance;
  }

  public function __destruct()
  {
    $this->_config   = null;
    $this->_instance = null;
  }
}

?>
```

The `$config` variable is just my config file and I've used the class as follows :

```
$db = new Database($config);
$db->getInstance()->query(...);
```

Cheers,
Rarely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Database` is not singleton in your case, because you can create several instances of this class. If you need singleton, use static property for save instance. And remove constructor (declare it as private).

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

class Database
{

  private static $_instance = null;

  private function __construct()
  {
  }

  public static function getInstance()
  {

    $config = // Implement reading of configuration

    if ($this::$_instance == null) {
      try {
        $this::$_instance = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['database']['host'] 
            . ';dbname=' . $config['database']['name'] 
            . ';charset=' . $config['database']['charset'], 
            $config['database']['username'], 
            $config['database']['password'], [
          \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
        ]);
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
      }
    }

    return $this::$_instance;
  }

}

?>
```

Than you will use `Database` like this:

```
$db = Database::getInstance()->query(...);
```